# React default value not saved in select tag

Tags: reactjs

I have this simple code where I'm trying to add a product to my database, but the value for type will be "" if I'm not changing the value by clicking on another option in browser. How can I make it to take the first option in the select tag(regular value)?

```
function ProductForm (props) {
  const { onAdd } = props
  const [type, setType] = useState('')

  const options = [{
    label: 'regular',
    value: 'regular'
  }, {
    label: 'urgent',
    value: 'urgent'
  }]

  const addProduct = (evt) => {
    onAdd(...)
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className='product-form'>
      ///...///
      <div className='type'>
        <select onChange={(evt) => setType(evt.target.value)}>
          {
            options.map((option) => (
              <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>
            ))
          }
        </select>
      </div>
      <div className='add'>
        <input type='button' value='Add' onClick={addProduct} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProductForm;
```

Comment: probably `const [type, setType] = useState(options[0].value)` if you declare `options` beforehand

Comment: Now I feel like I asked a dumb question, thank you! :D